# Display an overlay when leaving a page in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I would like to display an overlay on the page, after the user clicks a link, but before the next page is loaded. My current code adds a class to the `body` element when the link is clicked, which displays the overlay.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').addClass('loading');
});
```

The relevant CSS is:

```
body.loading:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: -500%;
    left: -500%;
    right: -500%;
    bottom: -500%;
    z-index: 9999;
    pointer-events: all;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

This produces the expected result on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari.

Using WebInspector, I can see the following behavior:

- In Firefox and Chrome, the `loading` class is added to the `body` tag, and the overlay appears. It continues to display until the next page loads
- In all browsers, manually adding the `loading` class to the `body` tag causes the overlay to appear
- In Safari, if I stop the `click` event from propagating, the overlay displays.
- In Safari, as observed through WebInspector, the `loading` class is *not* added to the `body` tag when the link is clicked.

How can I display an overlay in Safari that will be displayed while waiting for the next page to load?

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS as well.  Additionally, use the Web Inspector to see if the class is actually being added - that will tell you if the Javascript is executing appropriately.

Comment: I've added those details @TFrazee